# Problema com Wget e POST

Tags: wget

Estou tentando baixar todos os PDF's do Diário oficial do DF para uma pesquisa acadêmica. O site é de domínio público, obviamente, então não é algo que seja incorreto fazer.

O problema é que se eu tiver que baixar clique a clique estou lascado (são mais de 700 DODF's por ano) então estou usando `wget`.

Depois de muita pesquisa acabei chegando nessa linha de comando, usando post-data, porquê o site é dinâmico (usa form & asp):

```
wget -r --no-parent --post-data "ano=2005&mes=11_Novembro" http://www.buriti.df.gov.br/ftp/default.asp
```

**Claro que dessa forma terei que rodar o wget uma vez pra cada mês e pra cada ano**. Mas dá trabalho mas muito menos do que se eu tiver que baixar um por um.

O código ficou dessa forma porque o site é em ASP e usa um `form` pra passar o mes e o ano e retornar os diários relacionados. A execução acima vai para a página certa (a estrutura que o `wget` recebe é a do mês correto, e o `wget` encontra os arquivos PDF nos subdiretórios).

O problema é que ao tentar baixar os PDF's retorna o erro:

> 405 - *Method not Allowed.*

Se alguem puder me ajudar fico muito grato.

Comment: Por favor traduza sua pergunta, este é o stackoverflow em Português.

Comment: Desculpe não sabia. Me cadastrei no site em inglês e automaticamente parece que fui transferido para o em português. Vou traduzir neste momento. Peço desculpas novamente.

Comment: Seria o caso de acrescentar na pergunta o sistema operacional que está usando, ou as possíveis linguagens de programação que poderiam ser usadas para auxiliar na tarefa. Um script de shell ou console poderia ajudar. Se bem que olhando melhor o endereço, me parece que um pequeno _crawler_ seria o caminho, pois tem o POST para filtrar a lista principal de links, para depois obter os "sublinks" para os arquivos em si.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta! Estou usando windows e uma versão externa do WGET (os comandos estão sendo passados via CMD. Sei que é bem amador mas estou enferrujado na programação. Se não houver alternativa de linha de comando para o wget, vou pesquisar como construir um crawler. Achei a sugestão excelente. Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Aeee consegui uma maneira! 

De qualquer forma passando para agradecer pela presteza e sugestões!!
Acabou que ao você falar do crawler, percebi que o WGET, embora não retornasse o PDF, gravava 1 arquivo com os links.
Usei um comando de console para concatenar todos os arquivos em 1, e converti em TXT. Daí foi só jogar no excel, tratar e extrair os links diretos para os pdf's (os quais não dão erro HTTP 405).
Joguei os links num HTML e voltei pro Wget! Dessa forma funcionou!!!

Forte abraço a todos e muito obrigado!